# Mobile used web app automation without Appium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, appium-android

Can we use normal selenium web automation to test a mobile web app by changing window size to mobile resolution? or do we need to use an emulator and appium?

Currently, I'm working in a company. I didn't use appium for mobile web app automation. What I did is an automated web app with selenium ,Robot Framework as a normal web application and changed the window size to mobile resolution. Is it right?

sample code for window size set for mobile size is shown below for more understanding...!

```
  open browser    https://sample.com    chrome
  set window size  440  717
```

Thanks for your help guys!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Appium if it's a mobile-based web application as this is the preferred way of end-to-end testing.
For mobile automation, you don't need to download Android Studio as it is an heavy-weight tool. You can make use of [avdmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager).
To create emulators, you can refer https://gist.github.com/mrk-han/66ac1a724456cadf1c93f4218c6060ae

Comment: Thanks. At the moment I have implemented automation for entire app user flow with normal web automation. Is it ok for now or should I change it to the appium?

Comment: If there are other high priority tasks in your plate then you can park this for now.

Comment: I tried to initialize to the appium with androidstudio. But even in the mobile web application should we use element locators as android elements. I used Appium inspector for capture elements. Can't we use the usual HTML web elements for automation of mobile web app with appium?I faced problems when I tried to locate elements in appium inspector.(xpaths and ids)

Comment: For Appium, you can make use of `UiAutomator` to inspect elements. You can refer my blog: https://blog.kiprosh.com/issue-resolved-with-uiautomator-to-locate-ui-elements-in-appium-android/

Comment: If you think my answer has helped you anywhere then you can mark my answer as accepted or +1

Comment: Actually, I tried it. But I haven't enough points to add it.

Comment: If I'm using a normal web browser for mobile testing how to change the size to mobile size? how to set the window size for mobile size?

Comment: You can make use of `Dimension` class to set window size

Answer (score 0):

*Hi guys, I found a clarification for this according to my question.I'm trying to automate a WebApp for mobile and I'm testing in a mobile chrome browser. So it is easy to find elements with appium.We will not need appium inspector to capture elements as we are automating a mobile web application.Not a Native Android app.*

https://appiumpro.com/editions/57-how-to-determine-element-locators-for-mobile-web-and-hybrid-apps

*Refer above link and inspect the elements. It's totally the same as we are doing normal web automation. The only difference is using the emulator and appium server to run the test.
It was a kind of major issue for me as a beginner.I think now it's been solved.*